# JavaFX (Using PieChar and XYGraph but beside each other)

Tags: java, javafx

I looked at the JavaFX API and got my two graphs I want working. Though I would like them both besides each other, since I'm new I have no idea how to do this. If someone could help it would be great! Here's my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;  
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.Group;

public class Main extends Application {
final static String housing = "Avg Housing Prices By Year";
final static String commercial = "AvgCommercialPrices By Year";

private static double[] avgHousingPricesByYear = {
        247381.0, 264171.4, 287715.3, 294736.1, 308431.4, 322635.9, 340253.0, 363153.7
};

private static double[] avgCommercialPricesByYear = {
        1121585.3, 1219479.5, 1246354.2, 1295364.8, 1335932.6, 1472362.0, 1583521.9, 1613246.3
};

private static String[] ageGroups = {
        "18-25", "26-35", "36-45", "46-55", "56-65", "65+"
};

private static int[] purchasesByAgeGroup = {
        648, 1021, 2453, 3173, 1868, 2247
};


@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Lab06");
    stage.setWidth(1000);
    stage.setHeight(450);
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final BarChart<String,Number> bc =
            new BarChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    bc.setTitle("Lab 06");
    xAxis.setLabel("Housing");
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName(housing);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++){
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data( Integer.toString(2000 + i), avgHousingPricesByYear[i]));
    }

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName(commercial);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++){
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(Integer.toString(2000 + i), avgCommercialPricesByYear[i]));
    }

    Scene scene  = new Scene(new Group());

    bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2);

    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data(ageGroups[i], purchasesByAgeGroup[i]));
    }
    final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
    chart.setTitle("Purchases Example");

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(bc);
    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(chart);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need them beside each other, just put them in a [`HBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html):

```
@Override public void start(Stage stage) {

    // existing code, but remove this:
    // Scene scene  = new Scene(new Group());

    // and replace this

    // ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(bc);
    // ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(chart);

    // with this:

    HBox root = new HBox();    
    root.getChildren().add(bc);
    root.getChildren().add(chart);

    Scene scene  = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

A complete description of layout panes, such as `HBox`, is in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I wanted.